# how to add repository to Ubuntu 18.10 "Ubuntu Software"

Tags: software-center

I read the documentation at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html.en
... at step #2 after "Ubuntu Software launches" there is no tab "Software & Updates" just 
"ALL  INSTALLED   UPDATES".
"ALL" and "INSTALLED" only show applications already installed so I look at "UPDATES" ... but it only tells me that my system is already "up to date".
The 'help.ubuntu.com' directions for "addremove-sources" is mis-directing me or else the "Ubuntu Software" application has been changed and no longer provides for adding repositories.
The FreeCAD page:

https://launchpad.net/~freecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-daily

gives the directions to add these repositories for their daily build for Cosmic 18.10:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu cosmic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu cosmic main

... but the Ubuntu help info on adding repositories is either in error or out of date for 18.10 it seems.
Any help would be appreciated as to how to correctly use "Ubuntu Software" application to add these repositories !

Comment: Ubuntu Software is for installing software, you want to add a new source for software (which must be done before you can add software), so you need to add the lines into "Software & Updates" (which is what I believe the documentation is talking about) - the 3rd party section is titled "Other Software" on my 19.04 box, though I'm not familiar with using it (I'd use command line)

Answer (score 0):

**Software & Updates** can be opened from Ubuntu Software, by clicking on Ubuntu Software's name from top panel while it's running (the documentation is a bit misleading). However, if you can't find it-

- Open the **Menu** button on top-side Dash (the left panel) and search for **Software & Updates**.
- Or, open **Terminal** (ctrl+alt+t) or  and type `software-properties-gtk` and press **Enter**.

To add PPA, go to the **Other Software** tab. However are you sure want to add FreeCAD Daily PPA? It'll provide unstable, developement version of FreeCAD which will surely contain many bugs. If you just want to use FreeCAD (not test it for bugs), use the stable version (It should be available in Ubuntu Software and also in [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~freecad-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/freecad-stable)).